# Is there an (Amplitude max-min) function in Excel

Tags: excel, amplitude

i have search in excel an amplitude min max function that should be like that :

```
      myCell = Amplitude(Table1[varType])
```

that return immediatly amplitude of desired column .

All of this without creating a cell Max and min and doing like myCell = max-min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create such a function **(UDF)**

In a standard module enter:

```
Public Function span(rIn As Range) As Variant
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    span = wf.Max(rIn) - wf.Min(rIn)
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=span(A:A)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**